# why coproduct of one and one is two and not three?

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

Considering a category of finite sets, why is coproduct of 1 and 1, 2 and not 3?
Specially in terms of universal property.

Comment: Are asking how to show the universal property for 2 or to show it fails for 3?

Comment: I don't think anyone will be able to answer you unless you explain why you think it should be 3.

Comment: I am fairly new to catgory theory. Based on what I have grasped from (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coproduct), the only reason coproduct of 1 and 1 is 2 and not 3 is that there should be a unique mapping from 2 to 3. I am asking if someone can show me more concretly, perhaps using set notation, something similar to the graph we have in the mentioned page.

Comment: @Derek, As can be seen at (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coproduct), coproduct of x1 and x2 can be either x1 U x2 (union) or something else like Y. But according to universal property the first option has a better rank.

Comment: Just to clarify : when you say "and not $3$", do you mean "and not another number, for example $3$"? Would your question be the same for any other number? Or did you pick $3$ for a specific reason?

Answer (score 3):

Why would it be $3$ ?

Let $i_1, i_2: \{0\}=1\to \{0,1\}=2$, $i_1(0) =0, i_2(0)=1$
Let $f,g: 1 \to X$ be two maps.

Let $[f,g] : 2\to X$ defined by $[f,g](0) = f(0), [f,g](1)= g(0)$.

Then clearly, $[f,g]\circ i_1 = f, [f,g]\circ i_2 = g$. Moreover, clearly, a map such that these two equations hold must be defined in the same way, so that $[f,g]$ is the unique map making the appropriate diagram commute.

Therefore $2$ is *a* coproduct of $1$ and $1$. But $3$ is not isomorphic to $2$ in $Set$, and therefore it cannot be another coproduct.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. But would you please also tell me what is wrong with following statement?  Instead of the cardinality of set lets assume we count the number of the most inner elements of the set recursively. For example {0,{1,2}}=3.   And now we have:   $$ i_1,i_2 :{0}=1 \rightarrow {0,{1,2}}=3, i_1(0)=0,i_2(0)=2$$.   $$f,g:3 \rightarrow 2, [f,g](0)=f(0),[f,g](2)=g(0)$$

Comment: You can't possibly write $0=1$ and not feel something is wrong. The thing is, "counting the most inner elements", whatever it means (it's not clear from what you write), does not correspond to any set theory I know of. You can create a new set theory where what you wrote makes sense (I doubt it) but then you have to say what it is.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, let me put it another way. When you said {0}=1 and {0,1}=2 you meant that the cardinality of the set represents the natural number. What I am saying here is to change the representation definition as follow: First we flatten out the set meaning that combine all set elements as well as its sub or sub-sub elements into a single set and then take its cardinality. For example $$ \{1,2,\{3,\{4,5\}\}\} \rightarrow \{1,2,3,4,5\}=5$$

Comment: @user650585 Your representation is really weird as a number can be represented by multiple sets that have not the same cardinality: for example $4$ is represented by $\{0,1,2,3\}$ but also by $\{\{0,1,2,3\}\}$, the first having $4$ elements, the second having only $1$ elements... Taking functions as morphism between such things will not make it a category (how would you composed $X \to \{\{0,1,2,3\}\}$ with a function $\{0,1,2,3\} \to Y$?). The representation alluded by Max is von Neumann's inductive definition of numbers: $0=\emptyset$, $1 = \{0\}$, $2=\{0,1\}$, $3= \{0,1,2\}$, etc. [...]

Comment: [...] it is a consistent definition because $0 \subset 1 \subset 2 \subset 3 \subset \dots$, so it gives back the ordinary order relation on numbers. Plus for any finite set $X$, there is an iso $X \to n$ if and only if $X$ has $n$ elements.

Comment: @Pece I think Von Neumann's representation is also kind of a mapping (lets call it rep) that works as follow: $$ rep(\{0,1\})=1,rep(\{0,1,2,3\})=4$$ The same can be said about my definition:$$ rep'(\{0,1,2,3\})=rep'(\{\{0,1,2,3\}\})=4$$also as far as the order relation goes a modified subset definition can bring the order back to my representation. And finally regarding your last statement again it is a matter of definition. You can say the isomorphism exist if X has n atomic (non-set) elements or subelements.

Comment: The reason I defined this sort of definition for the natural numbers is $i_2$ to be able to inject {1,2}=2 in my first comment.

Comment: @user650585 The notion of "non-set" elements makes no sense in set theory. Of course it depends on your fondations but in a classic set-theory as ZFC, everything is a set! In particular any element of a set is a set. Moreover your post says "in the category of finite sets", so for example, $\{\mathbb R\}$ is an object in this category, but your _flattening_ consideration will not regard it as a finite set... There is something lacking in your question: either context or consistency. You need to be more precise about what you are asking.